# toDataUrl - saving Images in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have spent a lot of time building a dress-up game using KineticJS and I seem to have fallen at the final hurdle.

I have created a 'Snapshot' button which I wanted to allow my users to print the canvas to a window or tab. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Camera.prototype.takeSnapshot = function()
{

    var backgroundLayer = this.controller.view.getBackgroundLayer();
    var backgroundContext = backgroundLayer.getContext();

    var manikinLayer = this.controller.view.getManikinLayer();
    var manikinCanvas = manikinLayer.getCanvas();

    //combine background and 'manikin' layers
    backgroundContext.drawImage(manikinCanvas,0 ,0);

    //open data URL in new window
    var manikinImageUrl = backgroundLayer.getCanvas().toDataURL('image/png');
    window.open(manikinImageUrl);
};
```

Now as im sure you will have guessed already, this works in FF, Chrome, Safari for Win, but not IE or IOS Safari. Having done some research I believe all versions if IE flat out dont support this functionality?

I am just looking for an expert to confirm if this is true or not.

Also could someone please tell me how to fuse the the backgroundLayer and ManikinLayer together before they are printed out? I am getting the errpr 'Value could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement' on the 5th line of code.

Any help much appreciated as I am close to junking the project after having put in so much effort!

Comment: I'm not positive, but aren't there shims out there that will add this functionality to IE?

Comment: I dont know, are there? :)

Comment: You might try: http://code.google.com/p/fxcanvas/ or http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

Comment: I dont know about IE, but it definitely work on safari IOS (having made a few of such games myself)

Comment: `var manikinImageUrl = backgroundLayer.toDataURL();` I had used a statement like this... don't think you need to use getCanvas()

Comment: Thanks guys, markE's suggestion worked  a treat. I am just looking to combine the layers before printing now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your new window, create an image element with the source set to your dataURL:

```
    var win=window.open();
    win.document.write("<img src='"+manikinImageUrl+"'/>");
```

Comment: The only other outstanding issue is combing all the layers, as per my code above Im just printing the one (manikin) layer, but I want the background in there as well?

Comment: Did you try targeting the stage instead of each separate layer? You can do stage.toDataURL() too instead of just layers. The stage should contain all your layers right?

Comment: Its ok I sorted it,I needed to use layer.getCanvas().getElement()